# Any suggestions on Internationalisation resources?

Tags: .net, internationalization

I'm looking for resources on internationalisation in .NET for the more recent technologies - ie, WPF, Silverlight, .NET 4.0 etc. Does anyone know any good blogs, websites, or books on this subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard good things about

**[.NET Internationalization: The Developer's Guide to Building Global Windows and Web Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321341384)**

Comment: The author runs my local user group! I know the book was published a few years ago though, do you know how relevant it is for .NET 3.0 and later?

Comment: I don't think the practice of localized resource files and satellite assemblies has really changed since the book came out, although I haven't done much i18n. Have a chat with Guy at the next Local User group meeting on his recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163609.aspx.

Comment: I recommend using Google Translator for translations: http://translate.google.com/#.